# Yii2: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException'

Tags: php, web, yii2

I loves this community so much! And it seems now i need ask question by myself because at this time i get no luck with Google.

So, I can't get a PHP web-site to work. It gives such error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The "id" configuration for the Application is required.' in /var/www/www-root/data/www/abc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php:220 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/www-root/data/www/abc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(202): yii\base\Application->preInit(Array) #1 /var/www/www-root/data/www/somewebsite.com/index.php(20): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/www-root/data/www/abc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php on line 220
```

My index.php is:

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod');

ini_set('session.save_path', 'tmp');
session_start();   

require(__DIR__ . '/../abc/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../abc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../abc/common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../abc/common/config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../abc/common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../abc/common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../abc/common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../abc/common/config/main-local.php')
);

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();

?>
```

What can be wrong? I installed the Yii framework according to their manual.

Comment: There is something wrong with your config - you have duplicated files in bootstrap and config sections. Where did you get something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try, your config file (i.e. main.php)

```
return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend-example',
]
```

Comment: Now i get another error

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The "basePath" configuration for the Application is required.' in /var/www/www-root/data/www/abc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php:226 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/www-root/data/www/abc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(202): yii\base\Application->preInit(Array) #1 /var/www/www-root/data/www/abc-cs.ru/index.php(20): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/www-root/data/www/abc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php on line 226`

Comment: @Mr.Kru add the line `'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),` after the `id` you added

Answer (score 0):

Your config file main.php in config dir should return

```
......
return [
    'id' => 'your_app_if',
    'name' => Your App Name ',

    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'your_application\controllers', // the namespace for you application controller 
    'modules' => [],
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```